# Remote drop seatpost cable route

Tags: mountain-bike, seatpost, xc

What are some  options for a seatpost remote cables on frames without a pre designed route?

I'm considering a dropper post but would only do this if I was able to mount a remote as I like the continuous flow of being able to change things on the go.

The bike I spend most of my time on at the moment is a steel hardtail which under the top tube has a route for two gear cables and a brake hose (FD-RB-RD). I'm wondering if there was anyway to snuggly attach two lines to the brake hose hangers or if there is another tidy and safe alternative?

Answer (score 3):

It partially depends on where the cable comes out of the post. If it's from the top you can route the cable across the bottom of the top tube and up to the handle bar or down the seat tube and up the down tube. On the other hand, if the cable comes out of the bottom of the post, you can try to go out the bottom of the seat tube and up the down tube.

What is also becoming more common on frames without designated routing for dropper posts is to run a 1x setup and re-use the routing for the front derailleur cable for the dropper cable.

Answer (score 2):

The easy method is to use cable ties and route it where you like. Remember to add Biketape (transparent frame protection tape, aka helitape) to prevent the cable rubbing the paint off your frame etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option exits: to go without any additional cables from the dropper by using a wireless electronic one. No routing required. As a bonus, you can place the remote control anywhere you like.

Currently there is only one vendor to offer wireless seatposts though, and a single model they offer is Magura Vyron. It comes only in two sizes: ø30.9mm x 436mm and ø31.9mm x 436mm, both with 150mm of stroke.